# Heroku Scheduler with a Python Script

Tags: python, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I've been trying to get a scheduled job to daily using the Heroku Scheduler. However, I keep getting a weird error. It looks like it's trying to execute node instead of python. My script is nested in my backend folder and has a requirements.txt in that directory. What is needed for me to run a python script via Heroku Scheduler that I'm missing?

```
Jan 22 07:30:51 app/scheduler.1372 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
Jan 22 07:30:51 app/scheduler.1372   throw err;
Jan 22 07:30:51 app/scheduler.1372   ^
Jan 22 07:30:51 app/scheduler.1372 Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/frontend/python'
Jan 22 07:30:51 app/scheduler.1372     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
Jan 22 07:30:51 app/scheduler.1372     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
Jan 22 07:30:51 app/scheduler.1372     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
Jan 22 07:30:51 app/scheduler.1372     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
Jan 22 07:30:51 app/scheduler.1372   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
Jan 22 07:30:51 app/scheduler.1372   requireStack: []
Jan 22 07:30:51 app/scheduler.1372 }
Jan 22 07:30:51 app/scheduler.1372 Node.js v17.4.0
```

Heroku.yml

```
 setup: 
addons: - plan: heroku-postgresql as: DATABASE 
build: 
docker: 
web: front-end/fantasy-app/Dockerfile 
api: back-end/express-api/Dockerfile 
cron-service: back-end/scripts/KTCScraperScript/Dockerfile 

config: 
NODE_ENV: production 

run:
 web: node server.js 
api: node ./build/bin/www
```

Api dockerfile

```
# Base image
FROM node
# Make folder to put our files in
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/backend
# Set working directory so that all subsequent command runs in this folder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/backend
# Copy package json and install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
# Copy our app
COPY . .
# Expose port to access server
EXPOSE 8080
# Command to run our app
CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

Cron Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN touch /etc/crontab /etc/cron.*/*

# Copy hello-cron file to the cron.d directory
#COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/ktc-crontab

RUN echo "20 14 * * * root /usr/local/bin/python /app/ktc-rankings-scraper.py >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1" >> /etc/cron.d/ktc-crontab
COPY ktc-rankings-scraper.py /app/ktc-rankings-scraper.py
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/ktc-crontab
# Apply cron job
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
#RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/ktc-crontab

# set cron user
RUN useradd -m cronUser
USER cronUser

CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

Front end Dockerfile

```
# Base image
FROM node
# Make folder to put our files in
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/frontend
# Set working directory so that all
# subsequent command runs in this folder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/frontend
# Copy package json and install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
# Copy our app
COPY . .
# Expose port to access server
EXPOSE 3000
# Command to run our app
CMD [ "npm", "start-deploy" ]
```

Comment: What command have you entered into the Heroku Scheduler? Does your project also use Node.js?

Comment: My command is this `python ktc-rankings-scraper.py`. My project also uses node (express backend, angular front end) The python script just needs to run daily to scrape data and insert into the db.

Comment: The `/usr/src/app/frontend/` directory only exists in my dockerfile for the front end so I wonder if my dockerfile for the python install isn't running.

Comment: Oh, you're running via Docker. What is the [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) in your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Well, I have one as a docker but couldn't get it to work so I tried using the Heroku Scheduler Addon. My docker cmd is `CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log` but I get an `seteuid: Operation not permitted` error. Since I was stuck spinning my wheels, I tried to use the scheduler and got this error which seems to not have python. I did add the python buildpack but didn't seem to address the issue. I was wondering where the frontend directory was coming from and that is from the front end dockerfile. Maybe not all images are released and running properly. (i.e. cron dockerfile image)

Comment: I have no idea why that would be used as a `CMD`, but it looks irrelevant. Is your application _currently_ deployed using Docker?

Comment: I dockerized it locally and tried to deploy it. The client/server layers deployed correctly but need the database set up right to really function. Which was the issue since the cron job wasn't executing properly.

Comment: I'm still not clear how your application is _currently deployed on Heroku_. It might be via Docker but you keep saying things like "I tried to" and "but I couldn't get it to work". [What does `heroku stack` output for your application](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack#viewing-which-stack-your-app-is-using)?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. It is currently deployed in docker. My stack trace returns ```=== ⬢ application Available Stacks
* container
  heroku-18
  heroku-20 ```

Comment: Part of the issue I'm having is my cron docker container which is in python is unable to run so I've been testing to see if to forgo using docker and use Heroku to handle the scheduled job.

Comment: You shouldn't have "a cron docker container". You should just have "a container". Are you trying to use multiple containers somehow?

Comment: Yeah I set up a heroku.hml to spin up 3 dynos for the front end, back end, and cron. Are you saying I should only have one container for my cron

Comment: Here's my yml for reference

```
setup:
  addons:
    - plan: heroku-postgresql
      as: DATABASE
build:
  docker:
    web: front-end/fantasy-app/Dockerfile
    api: back-end/express-api/Dockerfile
    cron-service: back-end/scripts/KTCScraperScript/Dockerfile
  config:
    NODE_ENV: production
run:
  web: node server.js
  api: node ./build/bin/www

```

Comment: Please edit that into your question. It's very hard to read in a comment. // I'm saying you shouldn't have a dedicated container to run your cron job. I _think_ it's part of your back-end. Right?

Comment: The backend is really just an api layer (node) and should run separately from the cron just which is a python script that runs once a day.

Comment: But they're both logically part of the same back-end application, right?

Comment: Yeah they are in the same repo but I created a separate dockerfile for them cause I didn't know if there was a way to run both in once container

Comment: That doesn't mean you should have a separate `Dockerfile`. Believe we're getting close to the root of this now. What's the `CMD` in your _front-end_ `Dockerfile`?

Comment: I added all three dockerfiles to the question just in case.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a text file called runtime.txt in your root directory.

It should contain something like this:

```
python-3.8.12
```

After that, Heroku should use Python 3.8 when running your main command/script.

Comment: That's not what this file is for, and this is exceedingly unlikely to have any impact.